# Unity 2d change an object position to another

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im triyng to change a ball position to a empty gameobject but i can't do it constantly, when the empty gameobject assigned to a transform variable move, the ball don't move

here is my code
ball.transform.position = GrabPosition.transform.position;

Comment: Post more lines of code, to see what's happening. Another thing is, when is that you're calling the ````ball.transform.position = GrabPosition.transform.position;````?